# Bit-shifting to decide left or right direction when sliding down a pyramid

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am going through a solution to the "Pyramid Slide Down" problem (https://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-18/) and I need help understanding more intuitively the logic behind the solution for updating an index variable in the inner loop.

**The algorithm:**

```
int posSolutions = (int)Math.Pow(2, inputTriangle.GetLength(0) - 1);
int largestSum = 0;
int tempSum, index;
 
for (int i = 0; i <= posSolutions; i++) {
    tempSum = inputTriangle[0, 0];
    index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < inputTriangle.GetLength(0) - 1; j++) {
        index = index + (i >> j & 1);
        tempSum += inputTriangle[j + 1, index];
    }
    if (tempSum > largestSum) {
        largestSum = tempSum;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to understand how the `index` variable is updated and what it is used for. As I understand `index` is used so we cover all possible paths in the pyramid (as the person who solved it says "*it is used for deciding whether to go right or left"*). But I am having a really hard time grasping what is going on in this expression:

```
index = index + (i >> j & 1);
```

So, here's where I am at:

The inner-loop loops as many times as there are floors of the pyramid (-1 because of the top level). We have to make sure in every iteration that from the point we are originating from we have to cover all possible combinations of lefts and rights down to the  bottom floor - this is what `index` is used for. But I don't see how I would ever come up with that expression. I have tried going through diffrent pyramids floor for floor, logging different variables etc, but I can't wrap my head around the expression.

It would be a greatly appreciative for any inputs, suggestions, or explanations that anyone has. Thank you!

Comment: What is printed when you print out the value of index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how this algorithm works:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= posSolutions; i++) {
```

This loop is intended to examine every possible solution. The solution being examined is represented by `i`. It is essentially a bitmap with the same length as the depth of the triangle. For each bit, 0 means go left and 1 means go right so each value uniquely represents a path from the top to bottom of the triangle.

```
index = 0;
```

The `index` variable represents which value to look for in the 'current' level. It starts at 0 because there is only 1 value in the top level. Then it has to be increased by 0 (if going left) or 1 (if going right) for each subsequent level to ensure you are adding the correct value for the current solution `i`. For example, if you are in position 6 in one level then you need to move to either position 6 or position 7 in the level below depending on whether the respective bit is set in `i`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < inputTriangle.GetLength(0) - 1; j++) {
```

As you pointed out, `j` is the level of the pyramid, starting at the top.

```
    index = index + (i >> j & 1);
```

This is the expression that adds 0 or 1 to the index depending on whether the current solution wants to go left or right. `i >> j` shifts the bit in `i` for the current layer `j` to the right most position (i.e. technically the least significant bit). `& 1` then clears all bits other than the right most to leave you with 0 or 1. This value is then added to the index to point to the correct value for the current level.

For example, if the solution being looked at (`i`) is 12 (or 1100 in binary) and we are considering the third level, then `index` would be 0 and `j` would be 2. So `i >> j` would shift `i` right 2 bits to produce 11 (in binary). `& 1` would clear all bits other than the rightmost to produce 1. This is now added to `index` and we know to look at position 1 in row 2.

```
    tempSum += inputTriangle[j + 1, index];
```

This adds the value for the current level to sum.

```
if (tempSum > largestSum) {
    largestSum = tempSum;
}
```

Once you have the total for the current possible solution `i`, it's compared to the largest total found previously.

A couple of final points: firstly, the variable naming in the code you posted is not intuitive. Better naming would have made this algorithm much easier to understand. Secondly, there are much better algorithms for solving this problem than the brute force algorithm you've posted. They work from the bottom upwards and have the added advantage of being easier to understand (in my opinion).